# Lost Smart Object changes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I did about an hour's work on a Smart Object (an image I had placed in a file). I saved the smart image and closed it, but the changes did not appear on the original. I opened the Smart Object again, and it opened without any of the changes I had just made.

Some further research seems to suggest that this is because the original file was a .jpg, so when I saved my modified the file and saved it as a psd all my changes were lost, since Photoshop only checks the original .jpg for changes.

Is there a way of recovering my work? What is the location of the Temporary Items directory?

Comment: This also randomly happens on Photoshop CC. The saved changed on the smart object won't reflect on the original doc, even if you created it on the layers and not from a imported jpg IrealiTY's answer works around this and helps you get your file Would upvote, but it's a new account (which I made just to upvote this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your Photoshop Version?

Anyway, the regular temporary files are in:`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp`

But since Version CS6 there is the Auto-Recovery function, which automatically saves your files in case of a crash, it is worth a shot to check those, they are located here - if they are still there.
`C:\Users\YourUsername\Appdata\Roaming\Adobe\AdobePhotoshop CS6\Autorecover`

If you don't manage to locate any files in there, your work is sadly gone.

Comment: Do you know what the mac equivalents of these paths are?

Comment: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6/AutoRecover